# How to execute linux console app without ./

Tags: linux, console-application

Wow, let me first say that I've lost count how many answers I've found on this site.  You guys are awesome!

So, my first-ever question I'm posting is rather basic so I hope it's not badly received.  I did search to find an answer on google as well as here, but did not find an answer.

I just created a console app with code:blocks on linux, compiled it then ran within code:blocks.  Works just fine.  Then I opened linux bash shell, cd to where the binary was, then just tried running it from there, no dice.  A linux buddy of mine came over and told me to try ./ preceeding it.  Viola, that worked.  I was dumbfounded because I thought ./ was only needed to execute shell scripts.  I checked file permissions for the binary built by g++ and they are these:  -rwxrwxr-x

I've found other tutorials on building the Hello World application with code:blocks and they also say to execute on the command line using ./

Why is this so?  Also, how can I build a console application or any other binary application such that the ./ is not required to execute it?  I'm assuming it's possible somehow seeing as the vast majority of the built-in linux commands, such as grep, etc do not require the ./ to execute.

Thanks, guys.

Comment: You should add your app path into PATH environment variable: http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm . Post this kind of questions in http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run an executable on UNIX-like systems, you need to be aware of path resolution. If the path to the executable is not included in the `PATH` environment variable (and `.` sometimes isn't), you need to specify it yourself.

By appending `.` to `PATH`, like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

you can run executables from the current working directory without adding `./`. Note, however, this may be unsafe in a multi-user system, as other users can provide executables for you to run, in group or world writable directories, without your explicit permission(s).

Comment: Append . to the path is a big security hole. http://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default

Comment: Oh, I see, so the reason programs like grep, cat, etc can be executed without the ./ is because /bin and other areas like that are in the PATH?

Comment: Yep, that sure worked.  I just added to the PATH the 'Release' directory where the g++ compiler built the binary and then executed it without ./   Works!   Thanks guys, now I know, and knowing is half the battle!